# Angular routing, first page depends on user roles or claims

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-identity-3

My question is about angular routing. 
In fact I work on SPA application and the templateUrl of the first page depends on user roles (this information I have it in the user service).
As I cannot inject services in app.config how can I get the use roles information in this part to decide which url to return?

It means for the same route .when('/')
I have two or more templateUrl depends on user roles

Comment: You can use a function for templateURL, and that is injected with the route parameters. You can change the route parameters based on roles.

Comment: Yeah, I've made a function for templateURL, but my problem is in the user role how to get it in this function?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to pass route parameters with this syntax:

```
$routeProvider.
  when('/:UserRole' {
    templateUrl: 'anyPage.html',
    controller: 'anyController'
  });
```

Inside your controller (in this case "anyController") the route params can be queried by injecting the $routeParams service:

```
angular.module('yourAppName')
  .controller('controllerName', ['$routeParams','yourService', function($routeParams, yourService){
     //call your service function with the routeParams
     yourService.serviceFunction($routeParams)
  }]);
```

Comment: Thank you Martin, But realy I need to work with the root : when('/'

Comment: You can do it with when('/.. also